# How to Style a Disabled ASP.NET Buttons

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an asp button that I am styling using CSS.

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClockin" runat="server" Text="Clock In" class="FullWidthButton" />
```

CSS:

```
.FullWidthButton {width:100%;}
```

This works fine until I set `btnClockIn.Enabled = False` in my code, then it doesn't pick up the style. I tried adding the following CSS.

`.FullWidthButton[disabled="disabled"]{width:100%;}`

and

`.FullWidthButton[disabled]{width:100%;}`

but these don't seem to have any effect.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried changing "class" to "CssClass"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change "class" to "CssClass" and it should work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this its works for me:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClockin" runat="server" Text="Clock In" style="width=100%" />
```

Comment: I guess this would work but I don't want to change from using css to inline styles